# What can I do with a closed file object?

Tags: python, file

When you open a file, it's stored in an open file object which gives you access to various methods on it such as reading or writing.

```
>>> f = open("file0")
>>> f
<open file 'file0', mode 'r' at 0x0000000002E51660>
```

Of course when you're done you should close your file to prevent it taking up memory space.

```
>>> f.close()
>>> f
<closed file 'file0', mode 'r' at 0x0000000002E51660>
```

This leaves a closed file, so that the object still exists though it's no longer using space for the sake of being readable. But is there any practical application of this? It can't be read, or written. It can't be used to reopen the file again.

```
>>> f.open()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    f.open()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'open'

>>> open(f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    open(f)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Is there a practical use for this closed file object aside from identifying that a file object is being referenced but is closed?

Comment: Also, what is the alternative? An object can't delete itself, or modify the references to itself, so a closed file is essentially the only option.

Comment: @Lattyware I did not realise an object couldn't delete itself, though it makes sense as a practice.

Comment: You can check if the file has been "really" closed by f.closed

Comment: Note: you shouldn't generally have much to do with closed files because you want to handle them only inside `with` blocks and never reference them again, so you shouldn't even need to call `close()` explicitly.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's what I generally do, this thought just occurred to me when I saw a question about storing a list of file objects and I was curious about how closing the files would affect the data structure.

Comment: In theory, you could close and open a file represented by a `file` object multiple times (including the special case of creating the `file` object without actually opening it right away). However, those details are not exposed at the Python level, so creating an object automatically opens the file, and closing it is irreversible.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One use is  using the name to reopen the file:

```
open(f.name).read()
```

I use the name attribute when changing a file content using a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to write the updated content to then replace the original file with [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

```
with open("foo.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
    for line in f:
        if stuff:
            temp.write("stuff")

shutil.move(temp.name, "foo.txt")
```

Also as commented you can use the `f.closed` to see if the file is *really* closed.