# How to reopen a closed file?

Tags: python, file

I have a file object `file` that I opened with:

```
with open("text.txt","rb") as file:
    # read some line

file.write("texte")  # I know that doesn't work
```

I just want to know if I can open this file again, because Python has all the information about it, but it says that this file is closed.
I am trying to read some lines in the file and at the end, I will write a new line at the end of file, so I want to reopen this file in append mode.

```
>>> with open("test.txt","wb") as fich:
...     fich.write("test In ")
...
>>> fich
<closed file 'test.txt', mode ‘wb' at 0x7f3f49a3a4b0>
>>> fich.open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

I am calling a function that takes the file handle as parameter, so I can't reuse the open as the first time, because the name of the file is unkown inside the function.

Can I reopen the handle itself? Because I can use the same method and reopen it with:

```
with open("filename") as anotherfile:
```

Comment: No; file-like objects don't know about *how* they were created.

Comment: It would be helpful to copy-paste the **entire** stack trace rather than provide a screenshot. Many terminals require CTRL+SHIFT+C for copy rather than just CTRL+C. Your problem is that fich references a file handle, and that handle is closed. To open the **file** again, do exactly what you did before: `with open("test.txt", "a") as fich:...`.

Comment: If you're asking "is it faster to re-open an existing file object, compared to calling `open` a second time and creating a brand new file object?", you should consider whether this really represents a computational bottleneck that's worth optimizing. Even supposing it's possible, I wouldn't expect it to make more than a millisecond of difference, and you've already used a zillion of those by composing this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do with a closed file object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379488/what-can-i-do-with-a-closed-file-object)

Comment: i am passing this file handle as parameter in a function call , so the filename isn't known inside the function, so reopening the file with the same method is impossible inside the function , that"s why i'm asking how to reopen the file handle

Comment: @DJAMELDAHMANE cf my answer.

Comment: @bruno i know how to do that, that's not what i was looking for

Comment: @DJAMELDAHMANE the first part of my answer is EXACTLY what you asked for: reopening a file when you don't know the file name but have the `file` object (still opened or already closed, doesn't matter) at hand.

Comment: Open the file in `wb+` mode then inside the `with`  block you can `file.realine()` and `file.write(data)` once you call a `readline()` you have to reset the pointer using `seek(offset, whence)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply: reopen the file:

```
with open("text.txt","r") as file:
    #read some line

with open(file.name,"a") as file:
    file.write("texte") # now it works
```

Now you mention in a comment that:

> i am passing this file handle as parameter in a function call , so the filename isn't known inside the function, so reopening the file with the same method is impossible inside the function , that"s why i'm asking how to reopen the file handle

Now this is getting messy. A general rule is that a function should not close / reopen a resource it has been given by it's caller, ie this:

```
def foo(fname):
    with open(fname) a file:
       bar(file)

def bar(file):
   file.close()
   with open(file.name, "a") as f2:
      f2.write("...")
```

is bad practice - here `bar` should NOT close the file, only use it - disposing of the file being the duty of `foo` (or whoever called `bar`). So if you have a need for such a pattern there's something wrong with your design, and you'll be better fixing your design first.

Note that you could open the file for appending without closing the first handle:

```
def bar(file):
   with open(file.name, "a") as f2:
      f2.write("...")
```

but this may still mess up the caller's expectations.